# Image.show() results in a black screen

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Ok, so I'm trying to display a file I have in the same directory as my python script (called C.png). The first line just gives me a black bitmap image, while the second line gives me a colored image (like it should). But I cannot figure out why the first Image.open() is just giving me a black bitmap. Am I doing something wrong?

```
from PIL import Image

Image.open("C.png", "r").show()

Image.new("RGB",(300, 300), (0, 255, 0)).show()
```

Thanks!

EDIT: It appears that if I use a .jpg file, it works fine... I'm still not sure what is causing this. (A different .jpg file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11727598/2332721

Comment: Oh, I seemed to miss that, i'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: No -- it is not. A window is opening, but it is just showing up black.

Comment: It seems to be related to the program that is associated with the type of image you are using. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8932976/2332721