# FileNotFoundError in PIL image with relative path and absoulute path

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, file-not-found

```py
import PIL.Image as pilimg
import numpy as np

# Read image
im = pilimg.open("../dataset/start.jpg")

# Display image
im.show()

# Fetch image pixel data to numpy array
pix = np.array(im)
```

[image: Project directory]

(I'm no the author of the dataset, so I couldn't upload the whole project file.)

I'm trying to read the image with Pillow and convert it to NumPy array. However, I tried several methods such as using absolute path and methods in [PIL image.open() working for some images but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727598/pil-image-open-working-for-some-images-but-not-others) except method using OpenCV. However, it makes FileNotFound always.

The absolute path of `start.jpg` is `F:\GIST 강의 자료\2021 1학기\EC3202 신호 및 시스템\Programming Assignment\dataset\start.jpg`. and I believe the relative path to `start.jpg` from `src/program.py` is `../dataset/start.jpg`.

I'm using conda 4.10.1 and python 3.8.8 and windows 10.

Comment: you could try to get your actual working directory by doing `print(f"Current working dir: {os.getcwd()})`

Comment: @user_na Should I run it from bash shell or python prompt?

Comment: just make a print in the code before you use the image and run it like usal

Comment: @user_na I add code in comment and it show Current working dir: `F:\GIST 강의 자료\2021 1학기\EC3202 신호 및 시스템\Programming Assignment`

Comment: @user_na Is the basis of file import the working directory, not the location of the source code file that import image?

Comment: try as path: `os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'dataset/start.jpg')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232173/discussion-between-user-na-and-hyeonseo-kim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths are relative to the current working directory.
If you are unsure what the cwd is, you can find it out by doing:

```
print(f"Current working dir: {os.getcwd()})
```

Then you can use `os.path.join` to concat your relative path from there

```
os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'dataset/start.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

**Do not rely on os.getcwd for relative path**. Reason is shown below.

Instead, use `pathlib.Path`. For i.e. think of these structure.

```
x:/
 ├ A
 ┃ ├ 1.png
 ┃ ├ 2.png
 ┃ ├ 3.png
 ┃ ├ 4.png
 ┃ └ 5.png
 ┃
 └ B
   └ script.py
```

If you want to access *reliably* from `script.py` to *1.png*, you'd better use `__file__` to determine path of the script - as current working directory can differ from actual script location as shown in below example output.

```py
import pathlib
import os

print("Current cwd: ", os.getcwd())

# Get current script's folder
script_location = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

# get data folder
data_location = script_location.parent / "A"

# single file example
png_file = data_location / "1.png"

# alternatively can iterate thru directory
for file_ in data_location.iterdir():

    # print full path in linux style
    print(f"{file_.absolute().as_posix()}")
```

```
(Accessing file in different path in absolute path)

jupiterbjy@NYARUDESK/D: py X:\B\script.py
Current cwd:  D:\
X:/A/1.png
X:/A/2.png
X:/A/3.png
X:/A/4.png
X:/A/5.png


(Change directory)

jupiterbjy@NYARUDESK/D: 
❯ cd x:


(Now use indirect path)

jupiterbjy@NYARUDESK/X: py .\B\script.py
Current cwd:  X:\
X:/A/1.png
X:/A/2.png
X:/A/3.png
X:/A/4.png
X:/A/5.png
```

See how cwd - current working directory - differ for `os.getcwd` for each run.

However, no matter where you access that script either by indirectly or directly, outside or inside folder *B*, you can reliably access files relatively using `__file__`, `.parent` and `.joinpath` methods of `pathlib.Path` objects.

Check out documents of `pathlib` [here](https://docs.python.org/ko/3/library/pathlib.html), as I see you're Korean, this is linked to korean document.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the full absolute path to the image. for my case i did the following :

`Image.open(f'{os.getcwd()}/{project-name}/{image-file-name}.{file-extension}')`

Note that the image file must be in the same folder as your project.

For further details, refer to [`PIL.open`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) method to understand how the library handles file access.